# how to print many data from a single variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

i'm new to this sql-server coding, my question is

so in  this ID_Order contain many data from ID_Menu, as example ID_Order of O001 can have many data like M001, M002, M003, M004, M005

```
select @MenuID = ID_Menu from OrderDetail where ID_Order = @ID_Order
```

but then when i print it

```
print @MenuID
```

it only print `M005` 
is it possible to print all of the M001, M002, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare a cursor and loop through it:

```
Declare @MenuID varchar(100)

Declare curOrderDetail cursor local for
select ID_Menu from OrderDetail where ID_Order = @ID_Order

Open curOrderDetail

Fetch next from curOrderDetail into @MenuID

While (@@fetch_status = 0)
Begin
    print @MenuID
    Fetch next from curOrderDetail into @MenuID
End

Close curOrderDetail
Deallocate curOrderDetail
```

Answer (score 1):

Here no need of looping mechanisms. Try this below

```
 DECLARE @MENUID VARCHAR(MAX)='';
 select @MenuID = @MENUID+ID_Menu+',' from OrderDetail where ID_Order = @ID_Order

 --Removing last comma ',' with substring function.
 SELECT @MENUID= SUBSTRING(@MENUID, 1, LEN(@MENUID)-1)

 PRINT @MENUID
```

**Explanation:**

Here while you are printing `@MENUID` how comes the M005 came from  M001, M002, M003, M004, M005? Because it is in last in order. This means it is already looping inside to store the value in variable `@MENUID`. Now do the trick by capturing it in itself before looping jumps to next value in a set.

**Another way** of doing it by `Stuff` with `FOR XML PATH('')`. There are so many answers on stack over flow.

```
--STUFF Used to remove first comma ',' 
--For xml path used to generate comma concatenated xml.

SELECT @MENUID=STUFF ((Select ','+ID_Menu  from OrderDetail 
where ID_Order = @ID_Order FOR XML PATH('')), 1,1,'')
)

PRINT @MENUID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @MenuID VARCHAR(Max)

SELECT @MenuID = COALESCE(@MenuID  + ',', '') + CAST(ID_Menu AS VARCHAR)
FROM   OrderDetail 

SELECT @MenuID
```

You can also use `COALESCE` for `CSV`